# Mailing appears to have sent, but still "Running" after several hours

Tags: civimail

I have a mailing that's went out at 10:00am to about 1300 people.

My CiviCRM Mailer Settings say to batch every 100, and the cron job is set to run every 5 minutes. Under these conditions, I'd expect it to take no more than a couple hours to send all the emails.

When I look at the Report for the mailing, I can see a high percentage of successful deliveries, and a number of bounces that take us very close to 100%.

So I think the mailing has sent, but has not been marked Completed yet.

Answer (score 4):

After talking with josephmurray in IRC, he told me to (a) look for "stuck processes" and (b) to try and manually "Execute Now" the job from the CiviCRM cron page.

The latter didn't do anything more than my cron job which was set to run every 5 minutes.

As it turns out, the stuck process was the cron job itself. A "ps ax | grep php" showed the CiviCRM cron job running.

I wanted to know how long it was running so I ran 'ps -p 29753 -o etime=' (where 29753 was the pid of the process from the ps ax command above). It showed that that one cron job had been running for a number of hours. I deduced it was clearly "stuck."

So, the thing to note is that even if your cron job is set to run frequently, the log will show it running and finishing... but if your CiviCRM Mailer settings only allow 1 cron job to run (as mine do), then you're basically only seeing the cron job start, detect that another is already running, then shut down.

For me, the solution was to "kill 29753" - then the next time cron ran normally, it marked the mailing job Completed.

Comment: The new job in general processes a bunch of emails before exiting as completed.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same symptoms with CiviCRM 4.7 or 4.7.1 or 4.7.2 (mailing stuck at "running" without actually sending, but will send using Execute Now), this is apparently a bug without a fix (yet). See [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/mailings-scheduler-fails-after-upgrade-to-4-7-1) and [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17968). I spent a day trying to find the problem before I came across the bug report, so hopefully this post will save others some time.