# Mailings Scheduler fails after upgrade to 4.7.1

Tags: civimail, joomla, permissions, 4.7, cron

After upgrading to 4.7.1 (Joomla) I get the following error in the Mailing Scheduler log when activated by cron:

> Finished execution of Mailings scheduler with result: Failure, Error
>   message: API permission check failed for Group/get call; insufficient
>   permission: require access CiviCRM

My cron job calls php to execute cli.php. I have checked the user & group permissions & have tried granting the cron job's Joomla user superuser status, manually adding 'Access CiviCRM'. No joy.

Any clues please?

Comment: Just to rule out other possibilities: can you manually run the job with "Execute Now" from the Scheduled Jobs screen?

Comment: Yes, this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17968) in CiviCRM 4.7.1.

EDIT: Based on new information on this bug report, this problem does NOT exist when using wget.  Also, someone in the community has stepped up to pay for this bug to be fixed, so expect a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

For cross-reference, it appears this was not resolved on Joomla and is still an open bug.  See [dev/joomla#6](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/issues/6)